# How do I commit a vuex store mutation from inside a vue-router route that imports "store"?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

My goal is to commit (invoke/call) a mutation that I've defined in my Vuex store.

**store/store.js**

```
export default {
  modules: {
    app: {
      state: {
        shouldDoThing: false,
      }
      mutations: {
        setShouldDoThing: (state, doThing) => { state.shouldDoThing = doThing },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since I attach Vuex to my app, I can use `this.$store.commit` throughout the app in various components without issue.

**main.js**

```
import Store from 'store/store.js';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app-root',
  store,
  // ...etc
});
```

For example:

**exampleComponent.vue**

```
export default {
  created() {
    // This works!
    this.$store.commit('setShouldDoThing', true);
  },
}
```

Now I'd like to commit something from a vue-router Route file, in a `beforeEnter` method:

**exampleRoute.js**

```
import Store from 'store/store.js'

const someRoute = {
  path: '/blah',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    Store.commit('setShouldDoThing', true);
    next();
  }
}
```

However, when I try the above, I get the error

```
TypeError: _state_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.default.commit is not a function
```

There's lots of examples online of successfully using vuex getters by importing. And, if I `console.log()` the `Store` import, I can see my entire store structure

```
modules:
  app:
    actions: {someAction: ƒ, …}
    getters: {isStartingQuery: ƒ}
    mutations: {ariaAnnounce: ƒ, …}
    state: {…}
    __proto__: Object
```

**How can I import my Store and then `commit` a mutation from within a vue-router file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been googling for a very long time, and didn't find a stackoverflow answer or a vue forums answer for this specific case or issue, so below is the solution that I tested and works in my case.

For whatever reason, I can't trigger `commit`. However, I can simply invoke the mutation directly, and this change is then reflected throughout other components (as in, a "different" store wasn't imported).

**someRoute.js**

```
import Store from 'store/store.js'

const someRoute = {
  path: '/blah',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    Store.modules.app.mutations.setShouldDoThing(Store.modules.app.state, true);
    next();
  }
}
```

And later, in some component:

**someComponent.vue**

```
export default {
    beforeMount() {
      console.log(this.$store.state.app.shouldDoThing);
      // true
    }
}
```